# Rolling average with a grouped data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the firts three columns. As you can see the date is the same for any region: from 2021-01-05 to 2021-01-10.
So, I want to know if it is possible to automatically get a 3-day Rolling Average of Deaths (the fourth column in my df, which I did manually to example-purpose) for any region.

```
      REGION       DATE  DEATHS  ROLLING_AVG
0   AMAZONAS 2021-01-05       2          NaN
1   AMAZONAS 2021-01-06       4     3.000000
2   AMAZONAS 2021-01-08       3     3.000000
3   AMAZONAS 2021-01-09       2     3.333333
4   AMAZONAS 2021-01-10       5          NaN
5     ANCASH 2021-01-05      16          NaN
6     ANCASH 2021-01-06      11    15.666667
7     ANCASH 2021-01-08      20    16.333333
8     ANCASH 2021-01-09      18    17.333333
9     ANCASH 2021-01-10      14          NaN
10  AREQUIPA 2021-01-05      35          NaN
11  AREQUIPA 2021-01-06      34    40.333333
12  AREQUIPA 2021-01-08      52    45.666667
13  AREQUIPA 2021-01-09      51    48.666667
14  AREQUIPA 2021-01-10      43          NaN
```

I was trying to use `groupby` but had an error message.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.ExcelFile('muertespandemia.xlsx').parse('Sheet 1')
df=df.groupby(['REGION'])
df['ROLLING_AVG']=df['DEATHS'].rolling(3).mean()
df.head()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-7f5bdb9e87bb> in <module>
      6 df=df.groupby(['REGION'])
----> 7 df['ROLLING_AVG']=df['DEATHS'].rolling(3).mean()
      8 df.head()

TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rolling()` on `groupby` as follows:

```
df['moving'] = df.groupby('REGION').rolling(window=3)['DEATHS'].mean().reset_index(drop=True).shift(-1)
```

Prints:

```
df

      REGION       DATE  DEATHS  ROLLING_AVG     moving
0   AMAZONAS 2021-01-05       2          NaN        NaN
1   AMAZONAS 2021-01-06       4     3.000000   3.000000
2   AMAZONAS 2021-01-08       3     3.000000   3.000000
3   AMAZONAS 2021-01-09       2     3.333333   3.333333
4   AMAZONAS 2021-01-10       5          NaN        NaN
5     ANCASH 2021-01-05      16          NaN        NaN
6     ANCASH 2021-01-06      11    15.666667  15.666667
7     ANCASH 2021-01-08      20    16.333333  16.333333
8     ANCASH 2021-01-09      18    17.333333  17.333333
9     ANCASH 2021-01-10      14          NaN        NaN
10  AREQUIPA 2021-01-05      35          NaN        NaN
11  AREQUIPA 2021-01-06      34    40.333333  40.333333
12  AREQUIPA 2021-01-08      52    45.666667  45.666667
13  AREQUIPA 2021-01-09      51    48.666667  48.666667
14  AREQUIPA 2021-01-10      43          NaN        NaN
```